# routerLink not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm learning `Angular 6`.

I have designed my application structure in hierarchy form with following structure.

```
my_app
 |- src
    |- app
       |- layout
          |- admin-layout
             |- admin-layout.module.ts
             |- admin-layout.routing.ts
             |- admin-layout.component.html
       |- contacts
          |- contact-list
             |- contact-list.component.ts
             |- contact-list.component.html
          |- contacts.module.ts
       |- transaction
          |- amount-given
             |- amount-given-list
                |- amount-given-list.component.ts
                |- amount-given-list.component.html
             |- amount-given.module.ts
             |- amount-given.routing.ts
             |- amount-given.service.ts
          |- transaction.module.ts
          |- transaction.routing.ts
       |- app.module.ts
       |- app.component.html
       |- app-routing.module.ts
```

The source code and demo illustration can be found here: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcglvr

```
<a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

is working from `/transaction/amount-given/amount-given-list/` but not from `/contacts/contact-list`.

Since source code is quite long and hierarchical, I have added demo illustration on **stackblitz**.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have not imported `RouterModule` in `ContactsModule`.

```
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule
   ],
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this in your  contacts.module.ts

```
 import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

 @NgModule({
    imports: [
       RouterModule
     ],
```

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten to import RouterModule in your contacts Module

I've did that in your stackblitz and it worked.

Comment: This doesn't provide anything that Sanjay's answer lacks.

Comment: @EvanCarroll You should ask Sanjay since he has answered 2 hours after me!