# Angular: 7.2.14 - Yet Another Router Link Not Working Topic

Tags: javascript, angular

Sorry to revive a question. Im using Angular 7 and Im trying to use Router Link.

This is my app-routing-module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'locations'           , component : LocationManagerComponent },
  { path: 'locations/create'    , component : CreateEditLocationComponent },
  { path: 'locations/create/:id', component : CreateEditLocationComponent },

  { path: '404'                 , component : PageNotFoundComponent},
  { path: '**'                  , redirectTo: '/404'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is router link:

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/locations']" routerLinkActive="active">  test link </a>
```

When I click on link, nothing happens. The URL on browser changed but component is not loaded.
If I press F5, component is loaded and from that point on, routers link works.

I've tryed a lot of stackoverflow solution like writing link in any sort of variant like

```
<a routerLink="/locations" ...
<a [routerLink]= ['/locations'] ...
<a [routerLink]= "['/locations']" ...
```

With or without LinkAttive attribute. Putting

```
<base href="/">
```

in index.html etc....

Following this topic: [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51859992/routerlink-not-working-in-angular-6/51862253) I've tried to include Router in my Layout component:

```
import { Component, OnInit }  from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute }     from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.css']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route           : ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
[...]
```

but nothing changes.

The strange part is that after an F5, all routes works, even route to component not yet loaded.

In this topic [TOPIC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874788/routerlink-is-not-working-in-angular-6) the user resolved removing css class. I've tried to put my link in a completely cleaned component HTML and it not working (but still works after a refresh).

```
<p>
  dashboard works!
  <a routerLink = '/locations' routerLinkActive="active">  test link </a>
</p>
```

UPDATE: This is layout.component where route tag is.
I can't figure out how to have a Sidenav without having route-outlet inside it.

```
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over">
    <div class="profile_container">
        <span> User Name </span>
    </div>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <mat-list-item><a [routerLink]="['/locations']" routerLinkActive="active"> Locations
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
    <app-header  (toggleSidenav)="sidenav.toggle()"></app-header>
    <div style="padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: can you show your layout.component.html code? Its seems problem is there.

Comment: can you preapare stackblitz example for this question?

Comment: I posted dashboard.component.html thats has the same problem and its more simply

Comment: from which route you want to redirect to "/locations"?

Comment: do you import `AppRoutingModule` in your `AppModule`?

Comment: Yeah. Imported and put in "imports" 
`imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
[...]`

Comment: @Jake11 App.component.html has this code: `<main>
  <!-- Showing All Site Pages -->
  <span *ngIf='isLogged()'>
    <app-layout style="height:100%"></app-layout>
  </span> [...]`
and app-layout code is posted above

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: this answer is based on the previous version of your question, before you added the code of *layout.component.html*. So, instead of layout component, I am using the simplified dashboard component.

The below is working for me in Angular 8.1.

### app.component.html

`<app-dashboard></app-dashboard>`

means that the DashboardComponent is contained within (is the child of) the AppComponent.
No change to the default *app.component.ts*

### dashboard.component.html

```
<p>
    dashboard works!
    <a routerLink = '/locations' routerLinkActive="active">
        Locations test link </a>
</p>
<p><a routerLink = '/locations/create' routerLinkActive="active">
    Locations/create </a></p>
<p><a routerLink = '/locations/create/:id' routerLinkActive="active">
    Locations/create/:id </a></p>

<p>router-outlet is below:</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

All the links are working with click and with manually entering the url (eg: http://localhost:4200/locations/create/:id) in the browser and with reload (F5).

### New Components

Generated using the `ng generate component` command:

- Dashboard
- LocationManager
- CreateEditLocation
- PageNotFound

### app-routing-module.ts

The same as your file, but also added import statements for the newly generated components.

Comment: Thank you for the time you spent to help me. I figured out the problem as written above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured what cause the problem but I can't unserstand why and I was not able to reproduce in StackBlitz.

This was my app.component.html, the root of all app:

```
<main>
  <!-- Showing All Site Pages -->
  <span *ngIf='isLogged()'>
    <app-layout style="height:100%"></app-layout>
  </span>  
  <!-- Showing Login Page -->
  <div *ngIf='!isLogged()'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</main>
```

The App-Layout code is above.

THIS NOT WORKS!

I changed it with a simply:

```
<main> 
  <app-layout style="height:100%"></app-layout>
</main>
```

As you see from my question, Layout has its own router-outlet. 
I think the problem is the two router-outlet tag. Maybe Angular is not able to understand thats they are mutually exclusive. Maybe when I was clicking on menu, for some reason, Angular was updating the "first" router-outlet encountered and only after a refresh (F5), when the isLogged was already triggered and the app-layout was loaded directly, Angular knows which router-outlet to use.

In the new Way all pages, even Login, has to be child of AppLayout so every Layout component that's exists only if logged, has to be manually hide with *ngIf='!isLogged()'
A little price to pay to have routes works.